# Need comfortable information about local variables in a PHP-Script invoked on CLI

Tags: php, command-line, profiling, xdebug

My setup looks like this:

I work on WinXP, while my Test-Environment (Debian / Apache / MySQL / Squid / PHP / XDebug / ...) is running in a VMWare-environment. The project files are directly accessible in a shared folder, so I can do XDebugging using Eclipse.

Now I have a script that has to be invoked on the CLI and I want to perform something as similar as possible to the usual XDebugging ... not neccessarily live but I need information about which method is invoked when and what value is held by any local variable or attribute at any given time, basically.

How do I accomplish that?

I produced an XDebug-profile, but examining it in Wincachegrind did not reveal anything about variables whatsoever.

The CLI-Debugging from Eclipse-PDT seems to founder on the non-available access to the PHP-interpreter, as far as I understand the problem.

I would be happy not having to place echos everywhere.

I'm open for pretty much anykind of solution also if it is not trelated to XDebug, but I guess if there is one it's connected to it.

Best

Raffael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My investigations revealed the existence of some xdebug-features I didn't use so far which might do the job. Due to certain restrictions I couldn't try my hand at it.

But I figured that I could just require_once the php-script within another php-file which I just put into a folder that I could access from my browser. So I just started my XDebug-Session from Eclipse using this go-between.